# Determining eigenvalues and eigenvectors of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

I'm dealing with this problem:

Let $f(t) = (1-\frac{e^{it}}{2})^{-1} \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and let $T$ be the Operator with integral Kernel $K(x,y)= f(x-y)$

I have to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$. Also I have a Hint which suggests me to write $f(t)$ in complex Fourier sum form. Obviously I noticed that
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{e^{it}}{2}} = \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{e^{int}}{2^n}
\end{equation}

And $2^{-n}$ should be my Fourier coefficients..

But How Should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch solution:**

1) Show that $T : L^2(-\pi, \pi) \to L^2(-\pi, \pi)$ is the operator
$$ T(u)(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{e^{inx}}{2^n}\int_{-\pi}^\pi dy \ e^{-iny} u(y)$$

2) Every $u \in L^2( - \pi, \pi)$ can be written as a Fourier series,
$$ u(y) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} c_k e^{iky}.$$
Show that if $u$ has the above Fourier representation, then
$$ T(u)(x) = 2\pi \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{c_n }{2^n} e^{inx}.$$

3) Deduce that the eigenvectors are $e^{inx}$ (for $n \in \mathbb Z$), with corresponding eigenvalues are $2\pi / 2^n$ (if $n \geq 0$) or $0$ (if $n < 0$).

Comment: If $f_n$ are fourier coefficients shouldn't eigenvalues be $2\pi f_n$? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @JamesArten Apologies, I've corrected this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure this out better reading your suggestions

Comment: @JamesArten No worries, and if you have any questions (particular about why it's legitimate to exchange the order of some of the sums and integrals), then feel free to ask.

Comment: About 2) , in general shouldn't be $k \in \mathbb(Z)$?

Comment: @JamesArten Sorry, I'm screwing everything up!

Comment: @JamesArten For $u(y)$, the sum _should_ run over all $k \in \mathbb Z$. The conclusion is that $e^{inx}$ is an eigenvector for any $n \in \mathbb Z$, and if $n < 0$, then the corresponding eigenvalue is $0$.

Comment: Sorry the last question.. why just $2^{-n}$ and not $c_n 2^{-n}$ are eigenvalues?

Comment: For example, suppose that $u(x) = e^{12345ix}$. (So $c_n = \delta_{n, 12345}$.) Then $T(u)(x) = \frac{2\pi}{2^{12345}} e^{12345ix}$. So the eigenvalue is $\frac{2\pi}{2^{12345}}$.